# RabbitMq Consumers do Not Consume

Tags: masstransit, consumer

```
 public class RequestConsumer :
    IConsumer<StartFlowCommand>,
    IConsumer<List<StartAndNextCommand>>
{
    readonly IWorkFlowHandler _flowHandler;
    public RequestConsumer(IContainer container)
    {
        _flowHandler = container.Resolve<IWorkFlowHandler>();
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<StartAndNextCommand> context)
    {
        var result =await  _flowHandler.WorkFlowStartNext(context.Message);
        await context.RespondAsync(result);
    }


    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<List<StartAndNextCommand>> context)
    {
        var result = await Task.Run(() => _flowHandler.WorkFlowStartNextBatch(context.Message));
        await context.RespondAsync(result);
    }
```

Message type of  StartAndNextCommand can consume,but type of List are unable to consume,why?

Comment: but type of List<StartAndNextCommand> are unable to consume

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. We can only consume one message. You can have a new contract, like:

```
public interface StartAndNextBatch
{
    IList<StartAndNextCommand> Commands { get; }
}
```

and then have a consumer for that message type

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<StartAndNextBatch> context)
```

but you also need to publish that message type

```
await bus.Publish<StartAndNextBatch>(
    new { Commands = ... }
);
```